# OnBecameVisible() not call when gameObjects is on camera's field / UNITY

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, optimization, occlusion

i want to optimise my mobile game by not showing gameObjects that are not in the camera's field. I can't do Occlusion Culling because those gameObjects are instantiated and not static.

So i used

```
void OnBecameInvisible(){  Renderer.enabled = false; }

void OnBecameVisible(){  Renderer.enabled = true; }
```

It worked but sometimes, objects remain invisible.

I tried to use:

```
void Update()
{
    if (m_Renderer.isVisible)
    {
        m_Renderer.enabled = true;
        Debug.Log("show");
    }
    else m_Renderer.enabled = false; Debug.Log("not show");
}
```

But the performance drops badly.

How could i fix that?

Thank you. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity automatically uses `Frustum Culling` by default and doesn't render what the camera isn't looking at. Thus this is automatically implemented